# Python - Return rows after a certain date where a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that is approximately 350k rows and 12 columns of clickstream data. Below is a simplified snippet of what the data looks like. For each device I'd like to return all rows that appear after the purchase time.

```
   type_  deviceid   campaign_            time
   Click  device_1  Campaign_1  11/16/16 14:07
Purchase  device_1  Campaign_6  11/18/16 16:26
   Click  device_1  Campaign_5  11/19/16 14:17
   Click  device_1  Campaign_1  11/19/16 14:30
   Click  device_2  Campaign_4    11/6/16 7:00
Purchase  device_2  Campaign_2   11/9/16 21:56
   Click  device_2  Campaign_2   11/10/16 5:17
   Click  device_2  Campaign_3  11/12/16 19:19
```

I've tried using `.loc` to pull the results I need, but to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction or let me know what I need to do?

Comment: Is purchase time a column? Can you post df.head() that gives a view of all the columns?

Comment: Purchase time is not a column. The other columns were not relevant to the question at hand. The other columns are source, medium, order value, order number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define a function to filter the rows in each group, e.g.

```
def after_purchase(rows):
    # boolean mask indicating rows which are purchases
    is_purchase = rows.type_ == 'Purchase'

    # select timestamps from all purchases
    purchase_times = rows.loc[is_purchase, 'time']

    # grab the first (earliest) purchase timestamp
    first_purchase_time = purchase_times.min()

    # return all rows which occurred after the first purchase
    return rows.loc[rows.time > first_purchase_time]
```

Then, group your data frame by the device ID and apply the function to each group.

```
df.groupby('deviceid').apply(after_purchase)
```

```
            type_  deviceid   campaign_                time
deviceid                                                   
device_1 2  Click  device_1  Campaign_5 2016-11-19 14:17:00
         3  Click  device_1  Campaign_1 2016-11-19 14:30:00
device_2 6  Click  device_2  Campaign_2 2016-11-10 05:17:00
         7  Click  device_2  Campaign_3 2016-11-12 19:19:00
```

Comment: Great! It seems to have worked, but can you explain this part a little more?

`purchase_time = rows.loc[rows['type_'] == 'Purchase', 'time_'].iloc[0]`

its pulling values where `type_` is `Purchase`, but what is the `time_` referencing? I'm also not sure what the `.iloc[0]` at the end is doing. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: @Christopher please see my edit. I've expanded the one-liner in `after_purchase` which should hopefully make it more clear what's happening. Let me know if I need to elaborate more.

Comment: The indexing syntax is `rows.loc[row_labels, column_labels]` where I had used a boolean mask as `row_labels` and `'time'` as `column_labels`. Basically selects a subset of rows and a single column.

Comment: The `iloc[0]` was originally meant to take the first timestamp from the resulting list of purchase timestamps. However, I have updated the answer to use `min()` instead to ensure that the *earliest* timestamp is grabbed, not just the first one (in case your events are not chronological). If you can guarantee only one purchase per device, then switch back to using `iloc[0]`, since it's faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough explanation!